# Smooth scrolling through element by clicking anchor with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I have a fixed div (#navigation) on the left side of my page and a scrollable div (#content) on the right. When a link inside #navigation is clicked, it should trigger a smooth scroll to the correction section of #content. What happens is after you click the second time on the link, it goes to the wrong section of #content. You can check out all the actual source code in http://germanespitia.com

so..

## navigation:

```
<div id="navigation">
        `enter code here`    <div class="nav-item" data-page="about-me">
            <a href="#about-me" >
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item" data-page="projects">
            <a href="#projects" >
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item" data-page="portfolio">
            <a href="#portfolio" >
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item" data-page="contact">
            <a href="#contact" >
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## content:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="section" id="about-me">
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="projects">
        </div>
</div>
```

## jQuery:

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
   var goTo = $($(this).attr('href')); // selects element that was clicked
   var offset = goTo.offset(); //grabs position of element
   $('#content').animate({
      scrollTop: goTo.offset().top
   }, 1000);
   return false;
   $('#about-me h1').text(goTo.attr('href'));
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
   var goTo = $($(this).attr('href')); // selects element that was clicked
   var offset = goTo.offset(); //grabs position of element
   $('#content').animate({
      scrollTop: goTo.offset().top
   }, 1000);
   return false;
   $('#about-me h1').text(goTo.attr('href'));
   });
```

The offset that you scrollTo is offset of current position in the element you should fix

```
scrollTop: goTo.offset().top
```

To

```
scrollTop: $('#content')[0].scrollTop + goTo.offset().top
```

might works

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling is working properly only when offset is quite big it runs faster to complete in the 1000 ms you passed in to `animate` function. One idea is to calculate the time required to complete animation based on the difference in current offset and the one where we want to reach. Like this:

```
$('#navigation a').on("click", function () {
    var gt = $($(this).attr('href')),
        ofs = gt.offset(),
        tp = ofs.top,
        crOff = $('#content').scrollTop(),        
        anim = Math.abs(crOff - tp) * 100; //ESTIMATE TIME TO ANIMATE 
    if (x > 3000) x = 3000;//IF GAP IS TOO LARGE, IT IS PAINFULLY SLOW
    $('#content').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: tp
    }, anim); //USE anim VARIABLE TO CONTROL ANIMATION TIME
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vqce7/